# Put a struct in a struct

Tags: javascript, struct

Im making several structs on my code like that

```
var fruta = {
    x: Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.width-20) + 5),
    y: Math.floor((Math.random() * canvas.height-20) + 5),
    altura: 20,
    largura: 20
};
```

My question is if I want to put into a struct, other struct how would be?
(I made something like that but feel that is wrong)

```
var cima = {
        var x = {
            a:player.x,
            b:player.y
        },
        var y = {
            a:player.x+player.largura,
            b:player.y
        },
        var z = {
            a:player.centrox,
            b:player.y+15
        }
    },
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't have "struct", do you mean `object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
var cima = {
                x: {
                    a:player.x,
                    b:player.y
                },
                y: {
                    a:player.x+player.largura,
                    b:player.y
                },
                z: {
                    a:player.centrox,
                    b:player.y+15
                }
            }
```